# How to delete file passed as an argument as root?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I want to run a bash script from PHP which deletes a given file as root.
The PHP script:

```
passthru('./deleter.sh "hello.gif" 2>&1');
```

My bash script (deleter.sh) is:

```
rm "$1"
```

it has rights = 777 and owner set to root. But when run by a PHP script it does not delete anything and just says:

```
rm: can't remove 'hello.gif': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2):

While it could be possible to `setuid root` the bash script in question (if your OS distribution supports this), it's an extremely bad idea and a possible security hole.

Does the file to be deleted really have to be owned by root?

Comment: The file to be deleted is not owned by root. And PHP is not run as root. That's why I want to make a bash script to remove the file.

Comment: The bash script run by the PHP can run under different user than the PHP script itself only if (1) it has a _setuid_ attribute set and (2) the OS honors the _setuid_ bit for scripts. Otherwise it has exactly the same user ID and permissions as the PHP (Apache?) process.

Comment: Thank you. I tried chmod 4777 deleter.sh but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Tom, it sounds like you're confusing Unix permissions (the '777' you mentioned above) with 'rights'. Setting the file permissions on the script to 777 means that any user on the system can open and modify it - it does **not** mean that any user running it will be able to perform tasks with elevated permissions.

The purpose of setting ownership of a file (in your case, to root) is to restrict who can read, write or execute that file. There's a good explanation of how this works in the 'Notation of traditional Unix permissions' on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions)

Unfortunately, Mike's right, and it's an extremely bad idea to allow anyone to edit and run a file which will perform actions as root. If you need a script to delete a file owned by root, make sure only the root user can run the script (set the owner of the .sh file to root, and [chmod](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?chmod) the file to 744 or even 700) and put the deletion call in there.

Hope that helps.